# MySQL error: Incorrect Table Name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm pretty new to web development so there's a good chance I'm doing something pretty dumb here.

I'm using AJAX to send data to a PHP file which will use the data to run SQL commands to update a table. I'm dealing with editing articles, so my PHP file needs to know three things: The original name of the article (for reference), the new name and the new content. I also tell it what page the user is looking at so it knows which table to edit.

```
    $('#save_articles').click(function () {

    var current_page = $('#current_location').html();
    var array_details = {};
    array_details['__current_page__'] = current_page;

        $('#article_items .article_title').each(function(){

            var article_name = $(this).html(); //The text in this div is the element name
            var new_article_name = $(this).next('.article_content');
            new_article_name = $(new_article_name).children('.article_content_title').html();
            var new_article_content = $(this).next('.article_content');
            new_article_content = $(new_article_content).children('.article_content_content').html();

            array_new_deets = {new_name:new_article_name, content:new_article_content};
            array_details[article_name] = array_new_deets;

        });

        send_ajax("includes/admin/admin_save_articles.php", array_details);

    });
```

In the PHP file, I first retrieve the current page and store it in $sql_table and then remove the current page variable from $_POST. Then I run this.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){

        $original_name = $key;
        $new_name = $value['new_name'];
        $new_cont = $value['content'];


        $query =    "UPDATE 
                        `$sql_table`
                    SET 
                        `element_name`= '$new_name',
                        `element_content` = '$new_cont',
                    WHERE
                        `element_name` = '$original_name'";

        $query = mysql_query($query);


        if(!$query){

                die(mysql_error());

            }

    }
```

I always receive an error saying that 'sitep_Home' is an incorrect table name. Not only is it a real table in my db, but I've actually changed its name to make sure it isn't an issue with keywords or something.

If I instead run the query without the variable $sql_table (specifying that the table is called 'sitep_Home'), the query accepts the table. It then doesn't actually update the table, and I suspect it's because of the WHERE argument that also uses a variable.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure there are no whitespace in `$sql_table` variable?

Comment: `I first retrieve the current page and store it in $sql_table` ...how?

Comment: I was echoing the variables into JS alerts and it didn't look like there was any whitespace. But just ran it through trim() and now MySQL is accepting it as a table name. Unfortunately now it's saying my table doesn't exist.

Comment: there's a `,` that's not allowed before your where in the update statement.

Comment: Thanks, noticed that comma just a second ago. That was causing a different issue though that only arose after trimming my table name.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `$sql_table` as `'$sql_table'` if you are sure that this contain a right table name.
Like you are using other column's value
Check if this can help!!

Answer (score 0):

Dump/log your query before executing it - the problem should be quite visible after that (I suspect some additional characters in the table name).

Couple of things:

- you should never trust your users and accept everything they'll send you in $_POST, use whitelist for the fields you'd like to update instead
- your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, I recommend to use some framework / [standalone library](http://dibiphp.com/) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) at least, avoid [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) which will be deprecated in the future. Check this to get some explanation http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases

Comment: Thanks for the info on safety, I'll be sure to check it out.

Do you mean I should log the $query variable before running mysql_query()?

Comment: Yeah, that should help you in the future to debug problems like this, some cool debugger (instead of simple [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)) will make it even easier - I recommend [Tracy](https://github.com/nette/tracy) coming from [Nette](http://nette.org/) framework http://doc.nette.org/en/debugging

Answer (score 0):

Table names are case sensitive in MySQL. Please check if there is mistake in the case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to surround name of mysql table in query in this `` qoutes. When you dinamically create mysql table it is very important to trim($variable of mysql name table) before create, because if "$variable of mysql name table" have space in the edns or in the start mysql not create table. And the last when you call dinamically $variable of mysql name table in query you have to trim($variable of mysql name table) again.